# Get error when attempting to read elements from a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm so frustrated with a project I working on in which if there are duplicate elements in a table I want to hide them.  I find the duplicates without a problem.  The issues starts when I try to hide the duplicates.  I'm using vanilla JavaScript without any frame works or libraries.  I get this error that is really  hard to decipher.  Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined, 'e' is first duplicate element in the table

I don't have any hard coded data in my HTML its all JavaScript. I have never done a display none this way before so I thought I would reach out for some help.  My code is below.

Appreciating Your Help In Advance.

HP

```
//Create a HTML Table element.
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE"); 
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRow");


   //Get the count of columns.
    var columnCount = data[0].length;


    //Add the data rows.

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
       var row = table.insertRow(-1);
          for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) { 
          //Searching for duplicates            
           var num = data[i][0];
            for (var otherRow = i + 1; otherRow < data.length; otherRow++) {           
            var dup =  data[otherRow][0];
               console.log("What is the dup" + dup);
            if (num === dup){
                 console.log("duplicate");
                elems.data[dup].style.display = "none";

            }
         }



    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);


    }) ();
```

Comment: There is no `e` reference in your code above, so unfortunately the error cannot be recreated. Your code also appears to have a syntax error on the final bracket. Can you please provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are having? A JSFiddle, CodePen, or snippet would be ideal. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Hi that was a copy and paste error.  The only thing you are missing is my table I have attached.

Comment: Thanks for your response that is a copy and paste error.  The only thing you are miss is my table here it is   var data=[['e',0,1,2,3,4], ['a',54312,235,5,15,4], ['a',6,7,8,9,232],
         ['a',54,11235,345,5,6], ['b',0,1,2,3,4], ['b',54312,235,5,15,4],
         ['c',62,15,754,93,323], ['d',27,11235,425,18,78], ['d',0,1,2,3,4],
         ['d',54312,235,5,15,4], ['e',6,7,8,9,232], ['e',54,11235,345,5,6],
         ['e',0,1,2,3,4], ['e',54312,235,5,15,4], ['e',62,15,754,93,323], 
         ['e',27,11235,425,18,78]]; Unless you want me to resend everything.  I apologize